# question about intermediate step in trig identity

Tags: trigonometry

In reading this article on sinusoid operations, I would like to know why you need equation 1) as an intermediate step and how you derive it. It seems like you would apply the sum formula directly to arrive at equation 2).

http://scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics/a-refresher-on-waves-and-sinusoids/operations-on-sinusoids-advanced/

$$\cos(A + B) = \cos(A)\cos(B) - \sin(A)\sin(B)$$

\begin{array}
{l}A_i\cos(\omega t + \phi_i) &=& A_i\cos(\omega t)\cos(\phi_i) i A_i\sin(\omega t)sin(\phi_i) & 1)\\
&=&\left[A_i \cos(\phi_i)\right]\cos(\omega t) - \left[A_i \sin(\phi_i)\right]sin(\omega t). & 2)
\end{array}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation 1 isn't true. Presumably the author of the article meant to hit $-$ instead of $i$ to have $A_i\cos(\omega t)\cos(\phi_i) - A_i\sin(\omega t)\sin(\phi_i)$, which is the actual exact usage of the angle sum trig rule above. Then the author reorders the multiplications.

I imagine the author was afraid to combine the steps of using the trig identity and reordering, because many people are afraid of trig rules/would get lost if things weren't in perfect order. And then the author had a typo, which happens.